# SAS Cache Locator Service ins_41415 is NOT UP

Tags: sas

I am trying to restarting the SAS service using `./sas.servers restart`. I am keep getting the following:

```
    Stopping SAS servers
    Stopping SAS Environment Manager Agent
    Stopping SAS Environment Manager
    Stopping SAS Web App Server: SASServer2_1
    Stopping SAS Web App Server: SASServer12_1
    Stopping SAS Web App Server: SASServer1_1
    Stopping SAS Web Server
    Stopping SAS Cache Locator Service: ins_41415
    Stopping SAS JMS Broker
    Starting SAS servers
    Starting SAS JMS Broker
    Starting SAS Cache Locator Service: ins_41415
    waiting 30 ...
    waiting 30 ...
    waiting 30 ...
    waiting 30 ...
    waiting 60 ...
    waiting 60 ...
    waiting 60 ...
    waiting 60 ...
```

It seems like the `SAS Cache Locator Service: ins_41415` is stuck. After a quick search online, i found that i am suppose to delete some hidden file. Does any one know where are these hidden files and which one am i suppose to delete?

Comment: Stop the Cache Locator processes on the middle-tier machine. Check the gemfire.log file to make sure that the processes stopped completely.
Navigate to the GemFire instance directory (for example, SAS-configuration-directory/Lev1/Web/gemfire/instances/ins_41415/). Clean up this directory by removing the following files:
  gemfire.log
  gemfireCommand.log
  locator41415state.dat (or a similar file that is based on your configuration instance)

Comment: @cmjohns thanks, but now i am getting another error saying 'ERROR: Operation "status-locator" failed because: Could not load file "/opt/app/sas/9.4/config/Lev1/Web/gemfire/instances/ins_41415/.locator" because the file is empty', i don't recall deleting that file

Comment: If "/opt/app/sas/9.4/config/Lev1/Web/gemfire/instances/ins_41415/.locator" is actually present, try to delete it and retry the startup sequence.

Comment: Solution still works in SAS Foundataion 9.4 M6 - Windows server 2016. thank you!